# No option to show wlan password

Tags: wireless-networking, router, password-management

I have forgotten the wireless network password of my DLink router. When I try to login into router and find for WLAN password under wireless security option , the password is hidden(only stars/dots are shown).

I don't want to change its password because all other phones that are connected to the network in my home will be disconnected.

Would like to know if there is any way to show the wireless password.

[image: snapshot]

Comment: You are albe to look it up with your computer if it is connected to your network or even with your andoird phone if it is rooted. Here is a little guide on how to do it on Windows 7: http://www.howtogeek.com/116934/how-to-view-that-forgotten-wireless-network-password-in-windows/?PageSpeed=noscript

Comment: I dont have a computer that's connected to my wifi

Answer (score 0):

I know the Windows and Android sections of the following are accurate:
[How to view saved WiFi passwords in Windows 10 android and iOs](http://betanews.com/2015/12/28/how-to-view-saved-wi-fi-passwords-in-windows-10-android-and-ios/)

Since you mentioned several phones:

> If you're using Android, install a copy of the free file browser ES File Explorer.
>
> Navigate to the data/misc/wifi folder on your device -- it will not be visible on non-rooted phones.
>
> Open the file called wpa_supplicant.conf and you will see a list of saved Wi-Fi networks complete with their passwords.

If you have a WPS button, you can use that on a Windows machine and see if it works (you should have disabled it, but probably didn't), and then check "Show characters".

If you have a WPS pin enabled, you can use that as above, or just run [Reaver](http://www.kalitutorials.net/2014/04/hack-wpawpa2-wps-reaver-kali-linux.html) like your neighbors have possibly already done.

If you have neighbors with kids and strict parental controls on their own internet connection, ask their kids if they have your Wifi password (which they use to get around their parent's access controls).

Seriously, if your only concern is a few (less than 20) devices, then just reset it, patch the firmware, make sure it's in WPA2-AES mode, disable WPS, and set a new long random password that you type into all the devices once.